# Large Number of SharePoint Lists Serverside

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, data

I was contemplating the concept of using SharePoint lists for data storage (not what they're for, I know), and came up with the idea of having a unique SharePoint list for each user of the site, and have some data associated with that user stored in the list. Is there any reason I can't have a large number(Hundreds, perhaps. Less than 1500.) of SharePoint lists stored on our site? It seems like something I shouldn't do/shouldn't be able to do but I would like to know why before I move past the idea. Using SharePoint online if that matters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of information would you like to store that couldn't be in the user profile?

Comment: or just stored in local browser storage and retrieved with store.js or in a cookie

Comment: @RafaelBonametti Without going to deep into detail, I am attempting to implement a sort of badge system in my website that keeps track of which badges the user has earned, so it's a sort of custom data. Can the user profile be used to store data? If so, what kinds? Thanks.

Comment: It needs to be server-side storage.

Comment: Which SP version? Is it not something like this what you want? http://blog.sharepointlearn.com/2013/08/10/badges-badges-everywhere-but-not-a-drop-to-drink/

Comment: @RafaelBonametti SharePoint online. Not quite - with that implementation only one badge can be assigned to a user at a time. I am wanting users to be able to collect badges over time and have a persistent collection of them.

Comment: Gotcha. The thing with building using lists is that you are somewhat limited to expansions and it's good to build something that can be expanded. Sooner or later you are going to have a huge amount of lists and performance will get worst and worst. There are some third party tools for gamification though. Badgeville is one.

Comment: You're probably best suited doing this as a provider hosted app of some sort. Storing it list based means they could get to it and manipulate the data making it worthless. Woohoo! I've earned all the things!

Comment: @EricAlexander Haha true, but this is a company site. Since only employees will be using it I am implementing Honor System security measures. Aside from that, provider-hosted add-ins are not an option currently, and coding against sharepoint add-ins give me a headache to begin with. I would like to do the implementation fully in Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Answering one of your questions, yes, there is a limit of lists that you can have in SharePoint before performance starts to downgrade.

You can check [Microsoft's documentation on that](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

Comment: Good link - however I don't think the page addresses the limit of the max number of lists on any given SharePoint site. It seems only to address the number of items for any given list.

Comment: You're right. The same documentation but for SP 2010 shows 2000 lists per site. That can give you an idea https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single list if you configure it appropriately. 1500 users is well under the list threshold boundaries. You'd want to configure the list in such a manner that users can't really see other's data.

[image]

Users would need to have contribute permissions on the list as well to be able to perform CRUD operations against the list.